# CompletableFuture skipping some tasks when useing allof

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

trying to run many 3rd party api calls but some are seemingly skipped

the exact skipped method seems to be consistent across instances, however they are completely different methods after a rerun

method that is running basic logic:

```
    @Override
public Integer newGame(Integer id) {
    String deckId = api.createDeck().getDeck_id();
    id = gameRepo.save(new Game(id, deckId)).getId();
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> runners = new ArrayList<>();

    logger.info("new deck created deckid="+deckId);

    List<Card> cards = api.drawFullDeck(deckId).getCards();
    for(int i:new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}){
        runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "faceUp"+i, cards.subList(0,1).toArray(new Card[0])));
        cards.remove(0);
    }
    for(int i:new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}){
        runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "faceDown"+i, cards.subList(0,i).toArray(new Card[0])));
        cards.subList(0, i).clear();
    }
    runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "drawDown", cards.toArray(new Card[0])));
    runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "drawUp", new Card[0]));
    runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "winC", new Card[0]));
    runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "winS", new Card[0]));
    runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "winH", new Card[0]));
    runners.add(api.addToPileAsync(deckId, "winD", new Card[0]));

    CompletableFuture.allOf(runners.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).toCompletableFuture().join();

    return id;
}
```

method that is executing the api call:

```
    @Async
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Void> addToPileAsync(String deckId, String pileName, Card[] cards) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->template.getForObject("https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/" + deckId + "/pile/" + pileName + "/add/?cards=" +
                    Arrays.stream(cards).map(Card::getCode).collect(Collectors.joining(",")),
            Void.class));
}
```

config:

```
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
public Executor taskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("userThread");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

this is for a project where the requirement is to use an external api, i am aware there are more efficient ways to handle card management but this is the best way that i could come up with while utilizing this specific api as a replacement database

Comment: how do you know they are skipped?

Comment: You may want to place a try catch that wraps your external API calls inside your method lambdas. Sometimes if an exception is thrown inside a runnable that is executed in a future the exception is not easily seen and can cause strange behavior.

Comment: @Eugene I test the external api with postman and some expected behavior is missing from the response in postman that my code should've effected; the api manages a deck of cards, my code manipulates the cards in a certain way

Comment: @JakeHenry ive tried putting a try catch block in the lambda shown in my 2nd code block with a logger in the catch block and it doesnt seem to be catching anything

Comment: "and some expected behavior is missing from the response in postman that my code should've effected" - you seem to be a non-english speaking person, because this statement makes no sense. Could you may be clarify it?

Comment: @Eugene the external api manages a deck of cards, this deck of cards has a id associated to it, with this id i am able to access the api within the context of a already established deck of cards. i have the code create a new deck of cards than log the id of that deck of cards, afterwards it does things to that deck of cards using endpoints available on the external api. after my code runs i am able to access the external api via postman with the previously logged deck id to assure that the outcome of the code manipulating the deck is what I expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it wasn't my code that couldn't handle the asynchronous code, it was the external api. once i switched all of my *writeing* api calls to synchronized code it worked fine, however i can still asynchronously make *reading* api calls synchronously without issue.

Edit:
the final stats when testing on postman were 6sec. for the writeing endpoint but 1000ms. on the reading endpoint while makeing the same amount of api calls

Writeing logic:

```
@Override
public Integer newGame(Integer id) {
    String deckId = api.createDeck().getDeck_id();
    id = gameRepo.save(new Game(id, deckId)).getId();

    logger.info("new deck created deckid="+deckId);

    List<Card> cards = api.drawFullDeck(deckId).getCards();
    for(int i:new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}){
        api.addToPile(deckId, "faceUp"+i, cards.subList(0,1).toArray(new Card[0]));
        cards.remove(0);
    }
    for(int i:new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}){
        api.addToPile(deckId, "faceDown"+i, cards.subList(0,i).toArray(new Card[0]));
        cards.subList(0, i).clear();
    }
    api.addToPile(deckId, "drawDown", cards.toArray(new Card[0]));
    api.addToPile(deckId, "drawUp", new Card[0]);
    api.addToPile(deckId, "winC", new Card[0]);
    api.addToPile(deckId, "winS", new Card[0]);
    api.addToPile(deckId, "winH", new Card[0]);
    api.addToPile(deckId, "winD", new Card[0]);

    return id;
}
```

writing api call:

```
@Override
public void addToPile(String deckId, String pileName, Card[] cards) {
    String url = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/" + deckId + "/pile/" + pileName + "/add/?cards=" + Arrays.stream(cards).map(Card::getCode).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    val res = template.getForEntity(url, Void.class);
    logger.trace("status code: "+res.getStatusCode()+" ran request: GET:" + url);
}
```

reading logic:

```
    @Override
public GameBoard getGame(int id) throws Exception {
    GameBoard ret = new GameBoard();
    String deckId = gameRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(Exception::new).getGameId();
    val runners = new CompletableFuture[12];
    int index = -1;

    logger.info("querying deck deckid="+deckId);

    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "drawUp").thenAccept(x->ret.setDrawUp(x.getPiles().getDrawUp().getCards()));

    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "winC").thenAccept(x->ret.setWinC(x.getPiles().getWinC().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "winH").thenAccept(x->ret.setWinC(x.getPiles().getWinH().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "winS").thenAccept(x->ret.setWinC(x.getPiles().getWinS().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "winD").thenAccept(x->ret.setWinC(x.getPiles().getWinD().getCards()));

    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp0").thenAccept(x->ret.setFaceUp0(x.getPiles().getFaceUp0().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp1").thenAccept(x->ret.setFaceUp1(x.getPiles().getFaceUp1().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp2").thenAccept(x->ret.setFaceUp2(x.getPiles().getFaceUp2().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp3").thenAccept(x->ret.setFaceUp3(x.getPiles().getFaceUp3().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp4").thenAccept(x->ret.setFaceUp4(x.getPiles().getFaceUp4().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp5").thenAccept(x->ret.setFaceUp5(x.getPiles().getFaceUp5().getCards()));
    runners[++index] = api.getPileInfoAsync(deckId, "faceUp6").thenAccept(x->{
        ret.setFaceUp6(x.getPiles().getFaceUp6().getCards());

        ret.setFaceDown0(x.getPiles().getFaceDown0().getRemaining());
        ret.setFaceDown1(x.getPiles().getFaceDown1().getRemaining());
        ret.setFaceDown2(x.getPiles().getFaceDown2().getRemaining());
        ret.setFaceDown3(x.getPiles().getFaceDown3().getRemaining());
        ret.setFaceDown4(x.getPiles().getFaceDown4().getRemaining());
        ret.setFaceDown5(x.getPiles().getFaceDown5().getRemaining());
        ret.setFaceDown6(x.getPiles().getFaceDown6().getRemaining());
        ret.setDrawDown(x.getPiles().getDrawDown().getRemaining());
    });

    CompletableFuture.allOf(runners).join();

    return ret;
}
```

reading api call:

```
@Async
@Override
public CompletableFuture<FullResponse> getPileInfoAsync(String deckId, String pileName) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        String url = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/" + deckId + "/pile/" + pileName + "/list";
        val res = template.getForEntity(url, FullResponse.class);
        logger.trace("status code: "+res.getStatusCode()+" ran request: GET:" + url);
        return res.getBody();
    });
}
```

config:

```
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
public Executor taskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(30);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: You could show an example to provide more clarity and probably get more upvotes.

Comment: good that you got your problem resolved, bad that the way you asked the question, you made people invest time into it, without any meaningful outcome.

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress yes ill do that, thanks for the advise